# Element assignment in matrix function

Tags: matrix, function-construction

I have to define a function of two variables that yields a high dimensional matrix, with each entry containing a scalar function, that uses its coordinates in the matrix as input. like this:

```
f[x_,a_] := {{g[1,1][x]*a, g[1,2][x]*a}, {g[2,1][x]*a, g[2,2][x]*a}}
```

Is there any way I can assign the elements in a smart way without mapping the whole matrix by hand?

EDIT:
I've been asked for an example of `g`. This is taken out of the original code:

```
g[n_, m_] := Table[Chop[
    I*Conjugate[h[[n]][[i]]].(hx[[m]][[i]] - h[[m]][[i]])/
      step, 3*10^-3],
   {i, 1, Length[qvals]}];
```

Comment: Use `Array` or `Table`.

Comment: Do you have an example of what `g` is here?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: That's not a good example. It depends on many undefined free variables.

Comment: `f[x_, a_] = a Array[g[##][x] &, {2, 2}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
gs = Flatten @ Table[With[{m = m, n = n}, Sin[m #/n^2] &], {m, 2}, {n, 2}];
```

> ```
> {Sin[#1/1^2] & , Sin[#1/2^2] & , Sin[(2*#1)/1^2] & , Sin[(2*#1)/2^2] &}
> ```

```
f[x_, a_] = a Through[gs[x]];
f[u, b]
```

> ```
> {b*Sin[u], b*Sin[u/4], b*Sin[2*u], b*Sin[u/2]}
> ```